Migrating Apache WSS4j from 1.x to 2.x
We are migrating some old wss4j code.  I discovered the following old Merlin(Properties) constructor is no longer supported and I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to replicate it in the new version.
Old Code:
Properties props = new Properties();
props = PropertyConfigurator.readPropertiesFromFile("sv.properties");
props.setProperty(ConfigurationConstants.MERLIN_KEY_STORE_PASS,
            EncryptedPropertyConfigurator.decryptProperty(
            props.getProperty(ConfigurationConstants.MERLIN_KEY_STORE_PASS)));
try {
        merlinConfiguration = new Merlin(props);
        
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}


Looks like: merlinConfiguration = (Merlin)CryptoFactory.getInstance(props);  may be the answer
